# binary file not found when running bazel oci_image on local docker

Tags: docker, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-aspect, bazel-python

I have a bazel project (monorepo), that has some go and python code. I use bazel for building. For each of these, I want to create separate container. For creating python image, I am following this instruction.
https://github.com/aspect-build/bazel-examples/blob/main/oci_python_image/hello_world/BUILD.bazel

It seems, rules_docker is deprecated and hasn't been maintained for over a year, and rules_oci is what is recommended.

My python app runs using bazel run without any issues. Also, when creating the image, and loading it to docker images all work. But when I try to run, I get
`exec /parser/parser_bin: no such file or directory` even though the file is present in the docker container, I was able to look using docker cp.

**WORKSPACE** file

```
http_archive(
    name = "rules_oci",
    sha256 = "cf6b8be82cde30daef18a09519d75269650317e40d917c8633cf8e3ab5645ea5",
    strip_prefix = "rules_oci-1.7.2",
    url = "https://github.com/bazel-contrib/rules_oci/releases/download/v1.7.2/rules_oci-v1.7.2.tar.gz",
)

load("@rules_oci//oci:dependencies.bzl", "rules_oci_dependencies")

rules_oci_dependencies()

load("@rules_oci//oci:repositories.bzl", "LATEST_CRANE_VERSION", "oci_register_toolchains")

oci_register_toolchains(
    name = "oci",
    crane_version = LATEST_CRANE_VERSION,
    # Uncommenting the zot toolchain will cause it to be used instead of crane for some tasks.
    # Note that it does not support docker-format images.
    # zot_version = LATEST_ZOT_VERSION,
)

# You can pull your base images using oci_pull like this:
load("@rules_oci//oci:pull.bzl", "oci_pull")

oci_pull(
    name = "ubuntu2204",
    digest = "sha256:ccaef5ee2f1850270d453fdf700a5392534f8d1a8ca2acda391fbb6a06b81c86",
    image = "marketplace.gcr.io/google/ubuntu2204",
    platforms = [
        "linux/amd64",
        "linux/arm64",
    ],
)
```

**parser/BUILD.bazel** file

```
py_binary(
    name = "parser_bin",
    srcs = ["main.py"],
    main = "main.py",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [":fizz"],
)

pkg_tar(
    name = "parser_tar",
    srcs = [":parser_bin"],
)

py_oci_image(
    name = "parser_image",
    base = "@ubuntu2204",
    binary = "parser_bin",
    entrypoint = ["/parser/parser_bin"],
)

oci_tarball(
    name = "parser_tarball",
    image = ":parser_image",
    repo_tags = ["myname/fizzparser:v0.0.1"],
)

oci_push(
    name = "parser_push",
    image = ":parser_image",
    remote_tags = ["v0.0.1"],
    repository = "myname/fizzparser",
)
```

Run on the host without docker works.:

```
bazel run //parser:parser_bin
```

**Building image and running in docker.**
Build tarball worked

```
bazel build //parser:parser_tarball                                                       
INFO: Analyzed target //parser:parser_tarball (9 packages loaded, 46 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //parser:parser_tarball up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/parser/parser_tarball/tarball.tar
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.345s, Critical Path: 0.23s
INFO: 6 processes: 4 internal, 2 darwin-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 6 total actions
```

Loading to docker locally worked

```
docker load --input bazel-bin/parser/parser_tarball/tarball.tar                                           
Loaded image: myname/fizzparser:v0.0.1
```

Docker images also shows

```
myname/fizzparser           v0.0.1    b1210a6e568a   12 months ago   19.6MB
```

Docker run fails.

```
docker run  -it myname/fizzparser:v0.0.1                                
exec /parser/parser_bin: no such file or directory
```

To verify if the file is present, I ran `docker cp` and copied the file to a local directory, and `ls parser/` listed

```
ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 jd  staff   64 Feb 28 22:02 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 jd  staff   64 Dec 31  1969 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 jd  staff  160 Feb 28 21:49 dev
drwxr-xr-x  25 jd  staff  800 Feb 28 21:49 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 jd  staff   96 Dec 31  1969 home
drwxr-xr-x   4 jd  staff  128 Dec 31  1969 lib
drwxr-xr-x   5 jd  staff  160 Feb 28 22:02 parser
drwxr-xr-x   2 jd  staff   64 Dec 31  1969 proc
drwx------   2 jd  staff   64 Dec 31  1969 root
drwxr-xr-x   2 jd  staff   64 Dec 31  1969 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 jd  staff   64 Dec 31  1969 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 jd  staff   64 Dec 31  1969 sys
drwxrwxrwt   2 jd  staff   64 Dec 31  1969 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   9 jd  staff  288 Dec 31  1969 usr
drwxr-xr-x  11 jd  staff  352 Dec 31  1969 var
```

```
ls -l parser
total 56
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jd  staff   3561 Jan  1  2023 main.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jd  staff  21830 Jan  1  2023 parser_bin
drwxr-xr-x  6 jd  staff    192 Jan  1  2023 parser_bin.runfiles
```

What am I missing? The ubuntu base image doesn't seem to have any utilities. I am not sure following the instructions includes the python interpreter within the image.

---

Note: To check what happens if a docker couldn't really find the file, I changed the entrypoint.

```
py_oci_image(
    name = "parser_image",
    base = "@ubuntu2204",
    binary = "parser_bin",
    entrypoint = ["/parser/parser_bin1"], # This is incorrect 
)
```

The doing the same steps, and finally running the docker container gave slightly different results.

```
docker run  -it myname/fizzparser:v0.0.1                       
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/parser/parser_bin1": stat /parser/parser_bin1: no such file or directory: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

This seems to be the correct message when the file is actually not present. But when it was present when the entrypoint was set correctly to `/parser/parser_bin`, it was giving a different error.

How to debug this issue? If not with docker, is there any other way to run the oci container?

Comment: `binary = "parser_bin"` -- this looks wrong, it should be a label, i.e. `":parser_bin"`, I'd guess.

Comment: Tried changing it, but it didn't make a difference. :( Exactly the same error.

Comment: If I changed it to `binary = "parser_xyz"`, I get the error ` Tar parser/parser_image.app_layer.tar failed: missing input file '//parser:parser_xyz'` indicating, `parser_bin` and `:parser_bin` are treated the same way. In any case, this changing it to :parser_bin didn't fix the docker issue.

Comment: I'm guessing, but could you use `"$(locate parser_bin)"` perhaps? My suspicion is that the file gets included in the image but just not at the location you'd expect it.